# Using array.prototype.map with average function

Tags: javascript, arrays

After reading the docs on map method,I still cannot get this to work.
I am trying to use map to get the average of every pair of numbers in an array.Please help me understand whats wrong.

```
function getAverage(num1,num2){return Math.ceil((num1+num2)/2)}; 

function a(input){ var b = input.map(getAverage(num1,num2)); return b; } 

a([1,2,3,4]) //error num1 is not defined
//expected [2,4]
```

Comment: Average of every pair of numbers - do you mean adjacent pairs, or all combinations. Or, to ask that another way - can you tell us your expected output for `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: updated in the q.Thanks

Comment: If you want to pass a function to `.map` it should be `input.map(getAverage);` although this won't make your code _work_

Comment: Of course it isn't in your function you are passing num1 and num2 as parameters, these are not defined and you can use b either it doesn't exist inside the function getAverage.

Comment: I still dont get how `[2,4]`  is the expected result of *average of every pair of numbers* for an input of `[1,2,3,4]`. Am I being dumb? eg. The average of 1 & 2 is 1.5

Comment: @jamiec the OP wants to round up the average ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` projects a function to each element of a list/array, it simply "maps" a function over all the items.

```
[1, 2, 3].map(function (number) { return number + 1; });
// -> [2, 3, 4]
```

Therefor, first you need to have *pairs* of items in your "input" array, so it looks like this:

```
var numberPairs = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Until now, all you have are just *single* numbers but no pairs.

After conversion, you can use `map` like this:

```
numberPairs.map(function (pair) {
  return Math.ceil((pair[0] + pair[1]) / 2);
});
```

This will give:

```
[2, 4]
```

as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate the average using a map. A mapping pass a function to each element and then returns an array with the same shape. That is not the case, you want to get a value from an array, and you can use [the reduce method](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/javascript-array-reduce) for that.

```js
// adds two number
const adder = (a,b) => a + b;
// reduces the array adding all numbers and divides 
// by the array length
const getAverage = (arr) => arr.reduce(adder)/arr.length;
 
// outputs 2.5
console.log(getAverage([1,2,3,4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of `map()` to aggregate averages of every `n` values in the array:

```js
const sum = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
const getAverage = n => (averages, value, index, array) => index % n === 0
  ? [...averages, Math.ceil(sum(array.slice(index, index + n)) / n)]
  : averages

const result = [1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(getAverage(2), [])
console.log(result)
```